# SAPUI5/Fiori: Multiple Step Inputs in one View (Duplicate Id)

Tags: sapui5

I'm developing an app in SAPUI5/Fiori and I want to implement the "Step Input" control in a table for each row.
In the explored reference of Fiori, I copied the control code, but I currently get the following error:

> Core-dbg.js:2711 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error: adding element
>   with duplicate id '[..]--stepInput-decrementBtn'

My View looks like this:

```
<Table id="lineItemsList" width="auto" items="{/itemsSet}"class="sapUiResponsiveMargin">
            <headerToolbar>
                <Toolbar id="lineItemsToolbar">
                    <Title id="lineItemsHeader" text="{/lineItemListTitle}"/>
                </Toolbar>
            </headerToolbar>
            <columns>
                <Column vAlign="Middle">
                    <Text text="{i18n>detailLineItemTableIDColumn}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column hAlign="Right">
                    <Text text="{i18n>detailLineItemTableUnitNumberColumn}"/>
                </Column>
            </columns>
            <items>
                <ColumnListItem>
                    <cells>
                        <Label id="label1" text="{itemID}"/>
                        <StepInput
                        id="stepInput"
                        value="0"
                        width="120px"
                        min="0"
                        max="15"
                        step="1"
                        editable="true"/>
                    </cells>
                </ColumnListItem>
            </items>
        </Table>
```

I also tested to give the StepInput no id, but still the same error.

Comment: This was a framework issue which is no longer reproducible since https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/86be223b41ef4889a578ebad39918a33566f14d0 (Jun 22, 2017)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a look at your problem. I did some tests based on the SAPUI5 example https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.StepInput/preview

And found that the problems comes from the property ***editable*** which if it is manually set to true provokes the error you found.

You have several choices:

- You don't put this attribute, the field will be editable and it will work
- Match the value of the attribute to an element of your model (as in the example), it will work even when the value is  ***true***

Also you should create a ticket to SAP to raise this problem which is problem a standard issue.

Hope this'll help !

Answer (score 0):

Almiriad is right, this is a freaking bug in the latest versions, you can see it by debugging StepInput-dbg.js >> the decrement button creation method is sent twice (because the 'setEnaditable' checks the aggregation and creates the button)

Since true is the default value for editable property, you dont need it here :)

Comment: No problems, I'm glad I could help ! :) If you work on a licenced version of SAPUI5 you should open an OSS ticket on this topic, otherwise you can open a ticket on the github of OpenUI5 (I cannot my company network prevents me from going there.)